# How do you unit test the directive definition object?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

I would like to have a test that checks the directive definition object is "correct" and any changes to it will fail the tests.

How can I retrieve the definition object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$injector.get('blablaDirective')

Considering that your directive name is 'blabla'.

Note that it will return an array of one element.

Comment: OMG! How did you know my directive was called `blabla`?! :)
Also, thanks a lot.

Comment: because we're all the same about naming thing when we're testing :P

Comment: By the way, did you just know this, or is it documented somewhere?

Comment: I just happen to know that it was that for Filters, so i just tried it on my debugger for directive. I knew this because if you try to use a unknown filter it will say "unknow filter "<what I tried>Filter".